# "[index : string]" : IFoo notation in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can someone please tell me what the

`[index : string] : IFoo` means in

```
export interface IBar {
   [index : string] : IFoo;
}

export interface IFoo {
        CharacterName: string;
        DisplayName: string;
    }
```

I looked through the Typescript Revealed book and found nothing on that notation.  Is it supposed to be a collection of objects that implement IFoo?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is used to show the type of the result when an instance of the interface is indexed. When elements of type IBar are indexed by a string i.e `[someString]` the result will be of type IFoo.
e.g:

```
export interface IBar {
   [index : string] : IFoo;
}

export interface IFoo {
        CharacterName: string;
        DisplayName: string;
    }
    
    
var x:IBar; 
var y=x['asdf']; // Same as var y:IFoo = x['asdf']
```

Comment: Broken link unfortunately

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't required anyways. So removed the broken link now 