# How would you define the Typescript interface signature for an x-tag component

Tags: javascript, typescript, x-tag

The x-tag spec has the following signature in pure JS -

```
xtag.register('x-accordion', {
    // extend existing elements
    extends: 'div',
    mixins: ['superdefaults', 'otherdefaults'],
    lifecycle:{
        created: function(){
            // fired once at the time a component
            // is initially created or parsed
        },
        inserted: function(){
            // fired each time a component
            // is inserted into the DOM
        },
        removed: function(){
            // fired each time an element
            // is removed from DOM
        },
        attributeChanged: function(){
            // fired when attributes are set
        }
    },
    events: {
        'click:delegate(x-toggler)': function(){
            // activate a clicked toggler
        }
    },
    accessors: {
        'togglers': {
            get: function(){
                // return all toggler children
            },
            set: function(value){
                // set the toggler children
            }
         }
    },
    methods: {
        nextToggler: function(){
            // activate the next toggler
        },
        previousToggler: function(){
            // activate the previous toggler
        }
    }
});
```

Where obviously methods, accessors, and events can have multiple entries.

I am trying to define the Typescript equivalent of the object literal that is passed to the register function. Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you add what you've tried already? What aspect do you need help with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret for methods, accessors, and events is using a string indexer.  I was only going to write that part but that ended up being most of it anyways, so I finished it off.

```
declare module xtag {
    interface RegisterParams {
        extends?: string;
        prototype?: any;
        mixins?: string[];
        lifecycle?: {
            created?: () => void;
            inserted?: () => void;
            removed?: () => void;
            attributeChanged?: () => void;
        }
        events: { [name: string]: () => void; };
        accessors: {[name: string]: {
            get?: () => any;
            set?: (value: any) => any;
            attribute?: any;
        }};
        methods: { [name: string]: () => void; }
    }
    export function register(tagName: string, params: RegisterParams): void;
}
```

There's a decent explanation of indexers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577488/index-string-ifoo-notation-in-typescript).  On `accessors` there's no way to express that get and set are mutually exclusive with attribute.  The best we can do there is make them optional.